# jQuery Accordian DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a jQuery Accordian. Please see my code below:

**HTML :**

```
<div class="filter-cat colour">
    <h3>Colour <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h3>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""> Red <span class="count">(64)</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""> Dry White <span class="count">(78)</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""> Sparkling <span class="count">(24)</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""> Sweet White <span class="count">(16)</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""> Rose <span class="count">(6)</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""> Spirits & Liqueurs <span class="count">(16)</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="filter-cat vintage">
    <h3>Vintage <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h3>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""> 2013 <span class="count">(16)</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""> 2012 <span class="count">(12)</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""> 2011 <span class="count">(7)</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""> 2010 <span class="count">(5)</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""> 2009 <span class="count">(3)</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""> 2008 <span class="count">(1)</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""> 2007 <span class="count">(1)</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">view more</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$(".filter-cat h3").click(function(){
    $(this).parent('ul').slideToggle(400);
});
```

Basically when the user clicks on a H3 its is suppose to open the  below. My jQuery is wrong can someone tell me how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: h3 is not a chlid of ul, it's a sibling. You can use $(this).next(),  $(this).siblings("ul").eq(0), $(this).parent().children("ul"), or $(this).closest(".filter-cat").children("ul")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/)**.

You have a wrong selector in your jquery code :

```
$(this).parent('ul').slideToggle(400);
```

The `$(this).parent('ul')` will try to find the parent `ul` of the `h3` element when it's not exist.

You should select the `ul` element based on `parent()` :

```
$(this).parent().find("ul").slideToggle(400);
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(".filter-cat h3").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('ul').slideToggle(400);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-cat colour">
    <h3>Colour <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h3>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""> Red <span class="count">(64)</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""> Dry White <span class="count">(78)</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""> Sparkling <span class="count">(24)</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""> Sweet White <span class="count">(16)</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""> Rose <span class="count">(6)</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""> Spirits & Liqueurs <span class="count">(16)</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="filter-cat vintage">
    <h3>Vintage <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h3>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""> 2013 <span class="count">(16)</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""> 2012 <span class="count">(12)</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""> 2011 <span class="count">(7)</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""> 2010 <span class="count">(5)</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""> 2009 <span class="count">(3)</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""> 2008 <span class="count">(1)</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked=""> 2007 <span class="count">(1)</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">view more</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```